# What's the .angular directory in the project root about?

Tags: angular, angular13

According to [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure), there's nothing called *.angular* being regarded. Yet, in my project, I get that directory, immediately in the root of the project (on the same level as e.g. *package.json*).

It wasn't there before because my *.gitignore* would've barked at it. Currently, I'm trying out the latest Angular version, 13.0 and I conclude that it's a new addition to the tooling. Probably, it's some temporary stuff, since its contents are the following.

- *.angular/cache/angular-webpack*
- *.angular/cache/babel-webpack*

It was pointless to google *.angular directory dot what is* and the only (semi-)relevant hit I got was the docs linked above.

What's up with *.angular* directory and do I need to care (and/or version control it)?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#cache-options. If you used the Angular CLI, the `.gitignore` will tell you whether or not that should be included (it shouldn't).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I used Angular CLI but I got the *.gitignore* from my pre-generated repo not specific to Angular. Thanks!

Comment: > Angular now supports the use of persistent build cache by default for new v13 projects -> https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296#05df

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you're not using the `.gitignore` the CLI also generates/updates for you, but OK.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I **do** use *.gitignore*. But I fetched it from the pre-existing repo and there's nothing Angular-specific so that particular directory wasn't mentioned in the file. I didn't use the version created when I started the new project because I never do and it's the first time it surprised me. I'll know better for the next time. Or I simply will add `/.angular/cache` (copied form a new project) to the existing one. What do you think about that? Am I missing something additional?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

".angular/cache" folder should be ignored by your version control system (git, svn etc...)

Example for git, add this line to .gitignore file

```
.angular/cache
```

(source : ng new command with @angular/cli v13)

Answer (score 15):

If you generated your project by using Angular CLI, those will be already included in your `.gitignore` file as below.

```
# Miscellaneous
/.angular/cache
```

Caching is enabled by default in angular for the development environment. That's why you can see the `.angular` folder in the project root and of course it does not need to add in repo.

**Enabling and disabling the cache**

Caching is enabled by default. To disable caching run the following command:

`ng config cli.cache.enabled false`

To re-enable caching, set `cli.cache.enabled` to `true`.

**Cache environments**

By default, disk cache is only enabled for local environments.

To enable caching for all environments, run the following command:

`ng config cli.cache.environment all`

Comment: Thanks this is what I want, If someone need to know further, https://angular.io/cli/cache